# How to manage cross referencing in Object Oriented design ? (chess example)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am working on a Java project and I would like to a really clean "Object Oriented" design (the best I can...).

But I am struggling to understand how each object should reference the others.

Let's take the simple standard chess game example :

- Each player has a given number of chess pieces.
- Each piece belongs to 1 player

In my application, I will probably need to be able to retrieve the information ***in both way*** :

- Access the owner directly from the Piece
- Access all the owned pieces directly from a player

Here are my questions :

1. **What would be the best design ? Each entity should reference the other one(s) ?**
2. **Or X-referencing is just always bad ? Should I always access the objects in "single way" ?**
3. **Maybe should I make another class that manage the mapping between the Piece and the Players ?**

I do not like the X-ref solution, because it basically duplicate the information and it can potentially create inconsistency and a lot of work overload. But can it be avoided ?

I know those questions are a bit fuzzy but I do not think I can figure out alone ! Please help !

Thanks anyone.

Comment: Think of actual chess pieces. They have a color, which indicates the owner. They have a shape which let's the people know what kind of piece it is. I would not have the pieces directly point at the player, but I would have the black/white color.

Comment: You could have a ChessService that knows who owns white and who owns black. If a chess piece wants to know who owns it, it says chessService.whoOwns(WHITE);

Comment: It seems that asking about the _player_ has sidetracked the question of circular references. I think a more interesting question would be the relationship between pieces and the _board_. Does each piece know which square it occupies? Does the board know which piece occupies each square? Both? Neither?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those situations where following OOP as far as possible will lead you down a blind alley.

It might be simpler to think of it like this: a chess piece has a color, not an owner.

You can describe a color using an `enum`:

```java
enum ChessColor {
  BLACK,
  WHITE
}
```

I would advise against building a complicated class hierarchy for the types of piece also:

```
enum ChessPieceType {
  PAWN,
  KNIGHT,
  BISHOP,
  ROOK,
  KING,
  QUEEN
}
```

With these, defining a simple chess piece type is easy (although being Java a tad verbose!)...

```java
public final class ChessPiece {
  public final ChessColor Color;
  public final ChessPieceType PieceType;

  public ChessPiece(final ChessColor color, final ChessPieceType pieceType) {
    this.color = color;
    this.pieceType = pieceType;
  }

  public boolean equals(final ChessPiece obj) {
    return this.pieceType == obj.pieceType && 
      this.color == obj.color;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) {
      return true;
    }

    if (obj instanceof ChessPiece) {
      return equals((ChessPiece)obj);
    }

    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;

    result = prime * result + color.hashCode();
    result = prime * result + pieceType.hashCode();

    return result;
  }
}
```

But suppose you want to know the name of the player who owns a piece? I would argue that this is not a property of the *game* of chess, but a property of the *situation* in which it is being played.

```java
public final class ChessMatch {
  public final Player playerWhite;
  public final Player playerBlack;
  public final Map<BoardPosition, Piece> board;

  // ...
}
```

So to answer your sepecific questions...

**Access the owner directly from the Piece**

This does not make sense to do, since the owner of a piece is not a property of chess, only the color. Instead, access this via the `ChessMatch` (or whatever object).

**Access all the owned pieces directly from a player**

This can be implemented as a function from a `BoardState` to a list of pieces. For example:

```
  public List<ChessPiece> fetchPiecesForColor(final Map<BoardPosition, ChessPiece> board, final ChessColor color) {
    final List<ChessPiece> results = new ArrayList<>();

    for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : board.entrySet()) {
      // ...
    }

    return results;
  }
```